# Synchronous input and output in the terminal (like a chat) in python

Tags: python, terminal

I want to make synchronous input and output in the terminal in python (like a chat). For example, first thread prints the text to terminal from top to bottom while the other stream receives the user input at the very bottom of the terminal, without tearing the first stream. What's the best way to do this?

What do I want to achieve:

[image: The example]

I tried to make the most obvious way:

```
import threading, time

def output_proc():
    while True:
        print("Some output")
        time.sleep(1)

output_thread = threading.Thread(target = output_proc)
output_thread.start()

while True:
    print(input())
```

But as I expected, it does not work properly. The output of the program is erasing user input, and besides, the input field is not where necessary.

Comment: This may be slightly OS-dependent, because operating systems like Windows require use of `ctypes` to do this.

Comment: @Mous The linux version will suffice

Comment: In that case [ANSI escape codes](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x361.html) will be sufficient